# How to measure time between multiple GPIO ports changes with as little overhead as possible

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, gpio, raspberry-pi-zero

I have several GPIO ports that are all LOW, and want to measure the time it takes for each of them to change to HIGH. I have a working piece of code which gives reliable readings, but just looking at it makes me think 'there must be a more efficient way.'

The code should remain the same during the entire process, so that the amount of cleared ports does not affect the overhead time. (It should be as constant as possible.)

This kind of rules out using the following methods, which I have both tried:

Using the GPIO.RISING event.
Using threading for the handling of port changes.
Both lead to poorer results, because it involves more code and variables to handle the state change times, and passing the results along from the event handlers/threads back to the main code.

I realise that this by itself is not a very good way to get absoluty accurate measurements, but the results are good enough as is. (Background processes running etc. influence python performance, to give an example.) I am of course open to more accurate solutions, but just optimizing the python code would be a great start.

```py
whileCount=0 # createvariables
highCounter=0
portsCleared=[]
results=[]
portStates=[]

for port in portList: #set GPIO ports to IN mode
    GPIO.setup(port, GPIO.IN)

while (highCounter<portCount and whileCount < 1000): # loop until all ports are HIGH
    whileCount += 1
    portStates=[] # list in which the port states are stored
    for port in portList: #get all port states
        portStates.append(GPIO.input(port))

    portCounter=0   
    for port in portList: #process all port states
        portBoolean=portStates[portCounter]==GPIO.HIGH
        if portBoolean and not port in portsCleared: #this specific port has gone to HIGH so its time is stored and it is added to the cleared list
            portsCleared.append(port)
            results[portCounter]=whileCount
            highCounter+=1 #keep track of the amount of ports cleared, so the while loop can end once all ports are cleared
            #print [portCounter,highCounter,portsCleared]
        portCounter+=1
    time.sleep(.001)    

if whileCount==1000:#reached cap, set non cleared ports to cap
    portCounter=0   
    for port in portList:
        if not port in portsCleared:
            results[portCounter]=1000
    portCounter+=1
```

I am hoping to waste less time on overhead so the results will become a little more accurate.

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/63409/how-to-precisely-capture-the-arrival-time-of-an-input-edge

Comment: I understand correctly this would require the usage of events, which I have tried and did not give me reliable results. I suspect this is because it involves some kind of threading. I will add some more information in my question why this gives poorer results.

Comment: I haven't used pigpio myself, but based on the description of how it works in the answer I linked, it's probably the most accurate method you can use on the raspberry pi. Your code has a theoretical maximum resolution of >1ms, because of the sleep and the code runtime; The pigpio method timestamps the events in hardware from a 1MHz clock, giving a theoretical maximum resolution of 1us, 1000x better. (And the jitter should be a lot less, too, since it's done in hardware) To be absolutely clear: Based on the description, the timestamping in pigpio is done in hardware, not in event handlers.

Comment: As for events: You said that your experience was that events gave less accurate results than the code you show here, so I didn't bother suggesting them - BUT! I'd expect events to give better results that your current code. I was in too much hurry (which is an euphemism for "too lazy" :-) before to ask you about how you tested events, but given the update to your question, it seems you could improve the event-based code. (Ie. if the GPIO library forces too much overhead on you, use `select.epoll`/`select.select` to follow the `/sys/class/gpio/gpio*/value` files manually - no threads required!)